# How do I display many images (by imagefield) in all my nodes of a type?

Tags: drupal, cck

The thing is that I have hundreds of nodes each with 4 to 12 images all of them around the same size in an imagefield but I want to order that so it looks at the end in a grid or something like that.

I know that panels and views are the answer but I think I've seen all of the tutorials available but nothing.

If anyone know where can I find something like I need, I'll be very gratefull.

Comment: First of all your question is incomplete, What language are you using? What framework if any? What Database if any?

Answer (score 0):

Views is what you want.  There are lots of good screencasts and tutorials out there, but you might not find one on exactly what you're looking for, because Views + CCK are uber flexible swiss army knife kinda tools.

You'll want to create a view of this node type with the images, change the view from nodes to fields, set the display to grid, and then add the imagefield as the field.  Voila.